# how this following transaction trace generated?

Tags: tokens, transaction-trace

i got one tx hash: 0x7d2296bcb936aa5e2397ddf8ccba59f54a178c3901666b49291d880369dbcf31
How is the following transaction trace generated?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Geth clients have the `debug_traceTransaction` that allows stepping through the bytecode executed during a transaction.

Using the opcodes you can determine when a contract was invoked, CALL, CALLSTATIC, DELEGATECALL, etc. From examining the opcode parameters you get the contract addresses and calldata.

With that info you can reconstruct the contract call trace for verified contracts, and from the calldata the function identifier.